# Two Ember.JS ArrayControllers?

Tags: ember.js

I'm having a bit of a problem with an Ember.JS app I'm building:

```
    App.userController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
        content: [],

        init: function() {
            this.set('content', []);
            this.refresh();
        },

        refresh: function() {
            //Refresh Action
        }
    });

    App.supplierController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
        content: [],

        init: function() {
            this.set('content', []);
            this.refresh();
        },

        refresh: function() {
            //Refresh Action
        }
    });

    <h1>Users</h1>
    {{#each user in App.userController}}
        {{user.name}} - {{user.age}}
    {{/each}}

    <h1>Suppliers</h1>
    {{#each supplier in App.supplierController}}
        {{supplier.name}} - {{supplier.revenue}}
    {{/each}}
```

It works... but the users are displayed in the same list as the suppliers? If I remove the supplier controller, they display in the correct position. I think this is to do with having two instances of `Ember.ArrayController` but I'm not sure. It displays like this:

```
Users
-----------
Suppliers
-----------
User 1 - 
User 2 -
Supplier 1 - £100
```

When it should be displaying this:

```
Users
-----------
User 1 - 30 
User 2 - 25

Suppliers
-----------
Supplier 1 - £100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine. There is nothing wrong with having two instances of `ArrayController`. I made a jsbin based on your question and see users/suppliers in the right place. Check it out here: http://jsbin.com/ovitak/1/edit

Since your example didn't show how the data was being loaded, I implemented the refresh() methods to populate list of users/suppliers based on your expected output:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.userController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],

    init: function() {
        this.set('content', []);
        this.refresh();
    },

    refresh: function() {
      this.addObject({name: 'u 1', age: 22});
      this.addObject({name: 'u 2', age: 35});
    }
});

App.supplierController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],

    init: function() {
        this.set('content', []);
        this.refresh();
    },

    refresh: function() {
        //Refresh Action
      this.addObject({name: 'supplier 1', revenue: 200});
    }
});
```

Comment: in addition you probably want to use Ember.ArrayController.extend() instead of Ember.ArrayController.create();

Comment: Thank you! I found the problem. I had a variable called `me` that was declared in refresh. It wasn't declared properly so I'm guessing the two controllers were referencing the same `me` thus pushing an object to the same thing.